# OpenStreetMap/iOS: Markers and Routes Don't Work Together

Tags: ios5, openstreetmap

I am a newbie to OpenStreetMap, but have a fair amount of iOS development experience. I'm working on an app that will have an OpenStreetMap map on it, with markers that respond to a touch, and a route generated programmatically from an array of locations. I can make all the pieces work, but together: not so good.

Following examples, I put the markers on the map, and hook the mapView to a delegate, so I can respond to touches on the markers. Then, again following examples, I create a CMRoute and add it as a sublayer ([mapView.contents.overlay addSublayer:walkRoute.path];). Doing that essentially hides the markers under the route sublayer; they no longer respond to a touch.

Can anyone point me in a direction that will give me the means to have a mapView and a route sublayer and still be able to detect marker touches? I don't ask for code (though that would be nice) but thoughts on how this could be accomplished.

Thanks

Comment: from where are you getting turn by turn directions data to display on openstreetmap?

Comment: I'm not getting turn-by-turn directions. I just plot the route from a series of latitude/longitudes. I do that by creating a series of custom nodes and then passing them to: CMRoute* myRoute = [[CMRoute alloc] initWithNodes:customNodes forMap:mapView]. Then add myRoute as a subview to mapview.

Comment: thanks johnz. that clarified things little bit.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you are using CloudMades iOS maps library.

Comment: This one I mean: http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/iphone-sdk  I'm deducing that from your mention of 'CMRoute', but you should probably mention this in your question, given that this is in fact the technology you're asking a question about! It's not directly related to OpenStreetMap, unless you're also asking whether somebody has achieved this using different libraries (There may be other options:  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IOS#Libraries_that_help_iPhone_developers_use_OSM_maps )

Comment: True, I am using the CMRoute from CloudMade. Oddly enough, I worked on this project yesterday, and realized that the markers are now responding to touches! I made a number of changes to use the route-me library with off-line maps, and evidently one of the changes had the side-effect of fixing this marker problem. Unfortunately, I have to say that I don't know which change!